# What's the name of this component in AppKit?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, appkit

I want to know the name of sidebar-like component below.
Screenshot of AirMail
[image: Screenshot of AirMail]
Screenshot of Tweetbot
[image: Screenshot of Tweetbot]

Both of them have same width and similar appearance, so I thought that the component is available in AppKit but I couldn't find it in documentation by myself.

I've googled about NSTabViewController and NSSplitViewController, but I don't think they are the answer I want.

If you have any idea, please tell me!

Comment: Those look like custom  controls, not sure there's a standard control for that.

Comment: Oh really! What should I use to implement UI looks like those...? NSTabViewController, NSSplitViewController or other? I have worked with UIKit but am very new to AppKit

Comment: You can use a `NSTableView`/`NSTableViewController`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with that

Answer (score 1):

Airmail is using a subclass of `NSTableView` as you can see in the following screenshot showing Airmail and F-Script Anywhere side-by-side:

[image: Airmail]

[F-Script Anywhere](https://github.com/adamnemecek/FScriptAnywhere) is generally very useful for finding out which UI components an app is using. Another good alternative is the new [Debug View Hierachy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) feature in Xcode. To use this, open any macOS project in Xcode, then attach the debugger to the app you would like to inspect (Debug - Attach to Process) and click the Debug View Hierarchy button.